# Map multiple string Arrays using Dataweave into a single Array

Tags: arrays, json, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I have an array with a single index that has a JSON object that contains three different string arrays, which I have to map into a single one based on each index. for example all first index from each array into one single JSON object and so on...

Is it possible in Dataweave Transformation?

Input

```
[{
    "id": [
          "123",
          "456",
          "789"
        ],
    "name": [
          "Test Brand 1",
          "Test Brand 2",
          "Test Brand 3"
        ],
    "address": [
          "Via Roma 1",
          "Via Milano 1",
          "Via Napoli 1"
        ]
}]
```

Desired output:

```
[
    {
        "Key1": "123",
        "Key2": "Test Brand 1",
        "Key3": "Via Roma 1"
    },
    {
        "Key1": "456",
        "Key2": "Test Brand 2",
        "Key3": "Via Milano 1"
    },
    {
        "Key1": "789",
        "Key2": "Test Brand 3",
        "Key3": "Via Napoli 1"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following DataWeave expression, assuming that each array will always contain the same number of items:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
flatten(payload map (item, index1) -> 
    item.id map (item2, index2) -> {
        "Key1": item2,
        "Key2": item.name[index2],
        "Key3": item.address[index2]
    })
```

Output (address names were changed to make sure the transformation works as expected):

```
[
  {
    "Key1": "123",
    "Key2": "Test Brand 1",
    "Key3": "Via Roma 1"
  },
  {
    "Key1": "456",
    "Key2": "Test Brand 2",
    "Key3": "Via Milano 2"
  },
  {
    "Key1": "789",
    "Key2": "Test Brand 3",
    "Key3": "Via Napoli 3"
  }
]
```

Comment: The arrays does indeed contain the same amount of values, sorry for not specifying it. That works, many thanks :)

Comment: Glad it worked! Please, don't forget to mark this answer as accepted as it can help others that may have the same problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code where we don't need to do iteration (looping) two times and no need to flatten.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var id = payload[0].id
---
id map (item2, index2) -> {
        "Key1": item2,
        "Key2": payload[0].name[index2],
        "Key3": payload[0].address[index2]
    }
```

it will give the same result.

```
[
  {
    "Key1": "123",
    "Key2": "Test Brand 1",
    "Key3": "Via Roma 1"
  },
  {
    "Key1": "456",
    "Key2": "Test Brand 2",
    "Key3": "Via Milano 1"
  },
  {
    "Key1": "789",
    "Key2": "Test Brand 3",
    "Key3": "Via Napoli 1"
  }
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I took a swing at this just to make it dynamic so it would work for any amount of keys that were in the arrays. It gets a little confusing since you don't have access to the index in reduce. Enjoy!

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import indexOf from dw::core::Arrays
var data = [{
    "id": [
          "123",
          "456",
          "789"
        ],
    "name": [
          "Test Brand 1",
          "Test Brand 2",
          "Test Brand 3"
        ],
    "address": [
          "Via Roma 1",
          "Via Milano 1",
          "Via Napoli 1"
        ]
}]
--- 
(data flatMap valuesOf($)) map ((valuesArray) -> valuesArray reduce ((value, acc={}) -> acc ++ {
    ("key$(indexOf(valuesArray,value) + 1)"): value
}))
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "key1": "123",
    "key2": "456",
    "key3": "789"
  },
  {
    "key1": "Test Brand 1",
    "key2": "Test Brand 2",
    "key3": "Test Brand 3"
  },
  {
    "key1": "Via Roma 1",
    "key2": "Via Milano 1",
    "key3": "Via Napoli 1"
  }
]
```